# How do I set PyCharm font back to default size?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Using Cmd/Ctrl + Mouse Wheel to increase/decrease the font size quickly (when sharing screen vs when coding) and when I'm done changing it I'd like to make the font size for that open file back to the default size set in settings.

However, can't find a shortcut to do that. Do you know how I can set the font to its default size other than going to the preferences dialog?  My objective is to have a shortcut key that does that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type `Ctrl+Shift+A` to access the actions prompt and then type "reset fon" and type `Enter` to choose the "Reset Font Size" action.

If you want a keyboard shortcut for this, go to pycharm preferences in `keymap`. There is a search bar in the right of the keymap tab where you can type "reset font size" to quickly locate the "Reset Font Size" action. Right click on it and choose "Add keyboard shortcut" to add your own shortcut.

---

But if you often change the font size just to present the code to someone, you can use "Presentation Mode" for that. They are in the "view->Appearance" menu. You can also enter/exit presentation mode from the actions menu with `Ctrl+Shift+A` or add a shortcut to these actions in the keymap settings.

Comment: Awesome!   You answered both what I wanted to know and what I needed to know.